# class object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to recreate one of those old 2d space shooters, and have got most of it done, I have got stuck on the actual part of shooting though.

Also would I use pythagaros' theorem to calculate collisions between the bullets and the enemy as well as collisions between the enemies and the player?

Here is the code:

```
import pygame, random, os

pygame.init()
w, h = 1366, 768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption('SPACESHIPSHOOTER')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player:
    def __init__(self, pos=[w//2, h//7]):
        self.pos = pos
        self.player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('GameData', 'player.png'))
        self.player = pygame.transform.scale(self.player, (100, 83))

class enemy:
    def __init__(self, pos=[random.randint(0, 1366), 700]):
        self.pos = pos
        self.enemy = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('GameData', 'enemy.png'))
        self.enemy = pygame.transform.scale(self.enemy, (100, 83))

class bullet:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.bullet = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('GameData', 'missile.png'))
        self.bullet = pygame.transform.scale(self.bullet, (50, 41))
        self.exist = 0
    def update(self):
        if self.pos[1] < 700 and self.exist == 1:
            self.pos[1] -= 5

you = player()
enemies = [enemy()]
bullets = []

running = True
speed = 1.2
clock = 0
xv = 0

while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    clock += 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                xv = 8
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                xv = -8
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullets.append(bullet([you.pos[0], you.pos[1]]))
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                xv = 0
    you.pos[0] += xv
    if len(bullets) > 0:
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet.exist=1
            bullet.update()
    for badguy in enemies:
        if badguy.pos[1] <= 5:
            del enemies[enemies.index(badguy)]
            enemies.append(enemy([random.randint(0, 1366), 700]))
        badguy.pos[1] = badguy.pos[1] - speed
        screen.blit(badguy.enemy, (badguy.pos[0], badguy.pos[1]))
    if clock % 750 == 0:
        speed += 0.05
    if clock % 1200 == 0:
        enemies.append(enemy([random.randint(0, 1366), 700]))
    screen.blit(you.player, (you.pos[0], you.pos[1]))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

That's the code of the game and the error I keep getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/spaceshipgame/game.py", line 53, in <module>
    bullets.append(bullet([you.pos[0], you.pos[1]]))
TypeError: 'bullet' object is not callable
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`for bullet in bullets:` defines a variable of same name `bullet` which overwrites the class object. Rename either class or variable.

Conventionally upercase `CamelCase` is used for class names, `lowercase_underscored` for variables.

[Complete Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: It might be a good idea to give specific suggestions about renaming things. For instance, it's conventional to give classes `CapitalizedNames`, while instances (and other variables use `lowercase_names_with_underscores`.

Comment: @Blckknght I'll try to keep that in mind when programming.

Comment: @Blckknght I have enhancement my answer a bit.

Comment: @Slipknot1 In general, you should not use the exact same name for two different purposes. You got lucky here because the compiler was able to detect this error. Often reusing names will lead to errors that are much more difficult to track down.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line

```
for bullet in bullets:
```

where you overwrite the class `bullet` with the variable `bullet`. That's why the convention exists to write classes with capital letter `Bullet`.